# Creating a file with terminal

Tags: python, powershell, terminal

When I create a Python file with Powershell and save it, text such as variables go white instead of the usual blue and it does not detect errors like normal.There is no intellisense after save. How do I get it to be like creating a file with GUI.[This is what happens after I save after creating a file with the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu1qr.png)
[This is what happens when I created a file with the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SUMq.png)

I tried creating a file in terminal with 'code var4.py' but when I save it is not treated like a normal Python file even though on the bottom bar it says Python

Comment: What is the `code` command?

Comment: The code command is 'code' to create file

Comment: Shouldn't you be running the python file via `python`?

Comment: @Programmer-RZ what do you mean by that. I have the python interpreter installed aswell as the extension on vscode.

Comment: VSCode doesn't know how the file was created.  If you close the var4.py tab and reopen it by double-clicking, are the colors as you expect?  Overall, I can't really get too excited about colors not matching.

Comment: @ Tim Roberts It's not just about the colors. As i said it's about the intellisense and the fact that it does not recognise errors. When i close and reopen it does work. But I am trying to get used to using the terminal so thats why this is a problem for me.